# Why did not we have ccflags-m, but ccflags-y?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kbuild

I'm analyzing Linux Kernel `Makefile`s bundle. We can define an additional compiler flag to build external module with `ccflags-y += -std=gnu11 -Wno-declaration-after-statement -Werror`. I looked at [`Makefile.build`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/Makefile.build#L27) which external module build goes down to and did not even notice `ccflags-m` option defined. The full list of options:

```
obj-y :=
obj-m :=
lib-y :=
lib-m :=
always :=
targets :=
subdir-y :=
subdir-m :=
EXTRA_AFLAGS   :=
EXTRA_CFLAGS   :=
EXTRA_CPPFLAGS :=
EXTRA_LDFLAGS  :=
asflags-y  :=
ccflags-y  :=
cppflags-y :=
ldflags-y  :=

subdir-asflags-y :=
subdir-ccflags-y :=
```

As far as I understand what `y` and `m` means in `kbuild`, m - for loadable modules, y - for builtins. So it does not seem logical to specify compiler options with `ccflags-y`, not `ccflags-m`.

**QUESTION:** Why does not `ccflags-y` have `-m` counterpart `ccflags-m` for loadable modules?

Comment: You incorrectly understand intention of `ccflags-y`: it is applied for **all** targets, whether modules or builtins. See e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51461446/3440745).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, different suffixes `-m` and `-y` are needed only for determine the final purpose of the  **object files**:

1. `obj-y` are for build given object files as built-in, and `obj-m` for build them as modules
2. `subdir-y` and `subdir-m` are for more complex things.
3. `lib-y` and `lib-m` are the same: both builds objects into the library.

But flags (compiler or linker) are applied for the objects **unconditionally**, thus they have only `-y` suffix.

Typical scenario in Makefile looks like:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_FOO) := foo.o
ccflags-$(CONFIG_FOO_DEBUG)  := -DFOO_DEBUG
```

Here `CONFIG_FOO` is a *tristate* option (`y`/`m`/`n`) but `CONFIG_FOO_DEBUG` is a *bool* (`y`/`n`).